# WCF - SOAP client become null after created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a project using ASP.NET MVC5. In one of the action of a controller, I created a new `LocalHelper` object.

`LocalHelper` is a subclass which has a constructor to create a SOAP client for calling web services. I have set break point in the constructor and have verified that a valid SOAP client has been created in the constructor.

Here is my question:

I thought that in the action code, when a new `LocalHelper` object is created, there will be a valid SOAP client persistent within this object until this object vanishes. However, when I try to use this `LocalHelper` object to call some web services, I found that `soapClient` become null and thus throw exception already.

Why is this happening, and is there any way to make a variable referring a valid SOAP client and persistent within the object? Thanks.

---

*Below is the simplified code illustrating my scenario*

```
public ActionResult UserRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string code)
 {
   try
   {
     var helper = new MyHelper.LocalHelper();
     var userList = helper.GetUserList();
     ...
   }
}
```

*MyHelper.cs*

```
public class MyHelper
{
    public class LocalHelper
    {
        WebServiceSoapClient soapClient = null;

        public LocalHelper()
        {
           soapClient = MyWebServiceFactory.GetSoapClient;
           // Here I have verified that it does get a valid SOAP client
        }

        public List<String> GetUserList(){
           // Here, soapClient become null, and thus throw excpetion
            return soapClient.getUserList();
        }
    }
    public class RemoteHelper{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested classes are unorthodox. Perhaps if you removed the wrapper class and just made the call directly this problem would go away...

Comment: @TomRedfern maybe you are right. I have tried to replace soapClient with another integer variable, turns out primitive type variable works as expected, the value persists. I just wonder what's the difference between integer and WebServiceSoapClient